# I am new to Flutter and I am using VS Code for Flutter development. However, when I click "run," this error message appears

Tags: flutter

`Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1

'D:\Flutter_Projects' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

I run flutter doctor and this show

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale     en-US)

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.2)

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)

[√] Android Studio

[√] Connected device (4 available)

[√] Network resources

• No issues found!`

Comment: have you try run `flutter run` command?